# Google Sheets can view table as other way?

Tags: google-sheets

Have anyway can the table I convert to table II view? Like the image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get that exact result, you can use:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   LET(unpv,SPLIT(TOCOL(A3:A5&"|"&B2:D2&"|"&B3:D5),"|"),
       fc,INDEX(unpv,,1),
       rws,SEQUENCE(ROWS(fc)),
       {IF(COUNTIFS(fc,fc,rws,"<="&rws)>1,,fc),CHOOSECOLS(unpv,2,3)}))
```

However, you may be interested in this as well:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TOCOL(A3:A5&"|"&B2:D2&"|"&B3:D5),"|"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also try-

```
=HSTACK(
TOCOL(HSTACK(A3:A5,WRAPCOLS(,COUNTA(A3:A5),),WRAPCOLS(,COUNTA(A3:A5),))),
TOCOL(SPLIT(REPT(INDEX(JOIN(,B2:D2&"|")),COUNTA(A3:A5)),"|")),
TOCOL(B3:D5)
)
```

[image]